# How to detect browsers in os and open a url using Python

Tags: python, url, browser

I have been given a task of opening a url in browser using Python. There are many helpful code available which can open a url in `chrome` browser:

```
import webbrowser

url = 'https://www.google.com'
webbrowser.register('chrome',
    None,
    webbrowser.BackgroundBrowser("C://Program Files (x86)//Google//Chrome//Application//chrome.exe"))
webbrowser.get('chrome').open(url)
```

But what if the user do not have the `chrome` browser installed.? Is there any way we can get the list of installed browsers like `[chrome, firefox]` and then depending upon the installed browser, we can open the appropriate url in that browser.

I have to design this in such a way that it can run both in `windows` and `ubuntu`. Can anyone please share some useful suggestions. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use [`webbrowser.open(url)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/webbrowser.html#webbrowser.open) method to open a page in a browser that's default in OS

Answer (score 2):

I think you're over complicating it, just call the open function and it will open the url in the default installed browser.
https://docs.python.org/2/library/webbrowser.html

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open('http://google.com', new=2)
```